# JavaScript code to show current page title in scrolling tab bar

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to show page title in scrolling tab instead of my particular message, which may annoy visitors.

Is it possible to show the current page title instead of my message?

Here is the script:

```
msg = "MESSAGE";
msg = "MY MESSAGE" + msg;
pos = 0;

function scrollMSG() {
   document.title = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos); 
   pos++;
   if (pos > msg.length) {
       pos = 0;
   }
   window.setTimeout("scrollMSG()", 200);
}
scrollMSG();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.title` which has the title of the page. Also, don't use string in the `setTimeout` as it goes through `eval()`, instead, just pass the function reference.

```
msg = document.title;
msg = "MY MESSAGE" + msg; // don't know if you need this line
pos = 0;
function scrollMSG() {
    document.title = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos);
    pos++;
    if (pos > msg.length) pos = 0
    window.setTimeout(scrollMSG, 200);
}
scrollMSG();
```

Comment: The document.title will be updated every time you loop.

Comment: it wont @LeysamRosario

Comment: It will. Lets say the title is "Facebook". Everytime you loop the title will change to "MY MESSAGE Facebook" then the next loop will be "MY MESSAGE FacebookMY MESSAGE Facebook".

Comment: In simple words, i just want the current page title to scroll at least 5 times

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your script you should save the original title to a variable.

```
var OriginalTitle = document.title;

function restoreTitle() {
   document.title = OriginalTitle;
}

function changeTitle(title) {
   document.title = title;
}

var msg = "MESSAGE";
msg = "MY MESSAGE" + msg;pos = 0;
function scrollMSG() {
   changeTitle(OriginalTitle + " - " + msg);
   if (pos > msg.length) pos = 0
   window.setTimeout("scrollMSG()",200);
}
scrollMSG();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rotating title like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <script>
            function rotateTitle() {
                document.title = document.title.substring(1) + document.title[0];
            }
            setInterval(rotateTitle, 300);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle doesn't allow to set `document.title`, so I've created an example that rotates a message inside a `span` tag. It uses the same principle, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/npf3nqos/

Comment: It works fine here. Can you add more details to the question? Maybe we aren't understanding what you are trying to achieve.